# VideoColorizerColab.ipynb doesn't communicate with google drive links

Tags: google-colaboratory

DownloadError: ERROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found

Since yesterday I can't use my google drive files shared links with VideoColorizerColab.ipynb.  I get this error above all the time I try to colorize my videos.
 Does anyone know what's going on?  Thank you, Géza.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: Sorry for the quastion, but I'm not really professional in it. Could you describe me how to share it from step by step?  I'm using the simple and easy user friend https://colab.research.google.com/github/jantic/DeOldify/blob/master/VideoColorizerColab.ipynb.   Thanks, Géza

Comment: here's the link address of the copy of the notebook with the problem codes:    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1y-CqFR5s42_QmHzO9_pcsuFsaonQlyAt

Comment: I'm not sure if you can see it, so I created a shared link in my google drive of the Copy of VideoColorizerColab.ipynb.  Here's the public link of it:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1y-CqFR5s42_QmHzO9_pcsuFsaonQlyAt

Comment: I hope I didn't share private informations with the public with the link I pasted here in this topic...

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try mounting your Google Drive to your colab and copying the video to the colab rather than using the link to download the video.

The code to mount your google drive to colab is

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After this step, you can use all the content in your Drive as folders in your colab. You can see them in the Files section on the left side of your notebook. You can select a file, right-click and copy path and use the path to do any operation on the file.

This is  an example of copying

```
!cp -r /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/headTrainingDatastructure/eval /content/models/research/object_detection/
```